# Bootstrap Nested Collapse With Events Only On Parent Collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a nested Bootstrap Collapse with a shown event firing on both the parent and the child Collapse.  I need it to only fire on the parent Collapse and not on the child.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#accordion2").on("shown",function() {
    alert("shown!");  
  });
});
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/xb9K6/

Comment: I have a similar issue. I have nested collapse elements, and when I collapse the child, the .show() event triggers on the parent as well. I tried stopPropogation() with no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use `stopPropagation` method of the `event` object.

```
$(".accordion").on("shown",function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SPZZv/

Comment: Oh, and you have a colon at the end of your event line.

Comment: I have a similar issue. I have nested collapse elements, and when I collapse the child, the .show() event triggers on the parent as well. I tried stopPropogation() with no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: @JosiahSprague If you made the same mistake I did then its because you misspelt stopPropagation() as stopPropogation()

Comment: @JosiahSprague try to listen on events "show.bs.collapse hide.bs.collapse"