# Bootstrap collapse scrollTop scrolls to wrong element

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using this script to scroll to a shown collapse element:

```
$('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
  $('html, body').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
  }, 500, 'swing');
});
```

It works perfectly for everything except my navigation on very small screen sizes. On opening a menu I want it to scroll to the top of the nav. This works fine for my top level nav, but for my second level nav it scrolls to the top of the section rather than the nav.

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/inM9IUpyUY)

(use mobile preview -> click button to open collapsible nav -> click 'Link 1' -> scroll to bottom and click button to open 2nd collapsed nav)

As you will see it scrolls to the 'Link 1' heading rather than to the nav that has just been opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question being unanswered was bugging me a bit, so I took another look at it nearly 3 years later. I discovered that both the parent and the second nav were firing on the second 'shown' event.

I then found this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14325958/bootstrap-nested-collapse-with-events-only-on-parent-collapse), and the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14326280/2096845) held the key.

It was as simple as using the [`stopPropagation`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) method of the `event` object to prevent the parent collapse element being notified of the event as well.

```
$('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': $(this).offset().top
    }, 500, 'swing');
});
```

Updated [bootply](https://www.bootply.com/SiyZdDiBYd).